# Code builds for device, not for simulator... Expected identifier or "("?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, ios8, xcode6

I have this chunk of code in xcode 6 placed right below my import statements:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 80000
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
#else
#endif
```

When I select a physical device to run on, the projects builds fine. When I select the simulator to run on, I get an expected identifier error:

Expected identifier or "("

on this line:

```
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
```

I obviously have the correct number of parenthesis as it builds, runs, and completes its task fine on a physical device. If there is an explanation on this website for this occurrence, I have not been able to find it.

Thank you.

Comment: This is not the line that is causing the problem. You likely have mismatched braces earlier in your file that only apply when building for simulator.

Comment: How can certain braces only pertain to a device or a simulator?

Comment: Using `#if` preprocessor directives allows you to add/remove code before it is sent to the processor. If you have a directive that is only true for one of your two build targets, the code contained within will not be visible in the other. Consider: `#if IS_SIMULATOR { #endif`.

Comment: if you remove the two lines inside and just put something like nslog(@"here") - does it compile?

Comment: No it does not... I am trying to get the code from this question to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626797/no-visible-interface-for-cllocationmanager-declares-the-selector-requestalwa

Comment: I am not familiar with preprocessor directives and I can't find any good information about them. When I delete the two lines and simply add if (0==0) {} I get the same error so it's something wrong with my preprocessor code, not that specific line.